# ImportError: cannot import name '_validate_location' from 'folium.utilities'

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror, folium

I tried this code:

```
from folium.plugins import MarkerCluster

# let's start again with a clean copy of the map of San Francisco
sanfran_map = folium.Map(location = [latitude, longitude], zoom_start = 12)

# instantiate a mark cluster object for the incidents in the dataframe
incidents = plugins.MarkerCluster().add_to(sanfran_map)

# loop through the dataframe and add each data point to the mark cluster
for lat, lng, label, in zip(df_incidents.Y, df_incidents.X, df_incidents.Category):
    folium.Marker(
        location=[lat, lng],
        icon=None,
        popup=label,
    ).add_to(incidents)

# display map
sanfran_map
```

Moreover I tried the first `import` part like this  `from folium import plugins` but all the time it throws an error.
I hope you help me

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

The error message ImportError: cannot import name '_validate_location' from 'folium.utilities' indicates that the folium.utilities module does not have a function called _validate_location. This is likely because you are using an outdated version of Folium. To fix this error, you need to upgrade Folium to the latest version.
Upgrade the latest version -

```
    pip install folium -U
```

then -

```
    from folium.plugins import MarkerCluster
```

then use the 'MarkerCluster' object to add markers to your Folium map.
refer - [Folium documentation with code examples](https://realpython.com/python-folium-web-maps-from-data/#use-custom-data-binning)